# which config.xml do I work with?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Using phonegap, xcode, and cordova. I have it installed, running, and I am building in it. However most of the docs I come by seem to be dated, and reference an old plist file to be used in getting plugins working. Then when you find reference that bridge the gap they always specifiy use the config.xml. Problem with that, is in installing in to the letter, I have two config xml files. One above the www directory at the same level, and one within?

Which one would I alter to get the ability to change the alerts? So in particular I can use

```
navigator.notification.alert(obj.data, 'my app', 'Done');
```

Also I found some references to a phonegap-x.x.x.js and that never came with my copy of phonegap, I assume when they stoped using one format, and switched over to the new they may have dropped that as well but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

One file is **Cordova's xml file (www)** and the other is a **platform-specific config.xml**.

I add all changes in the config.xml above the www directory which works fine.
If you want to compile for iOS **&** android you may use the other one?